# Lost Metamask wallet

Tags: metamask

Yesterday my metamask wallet disappeared and was no longer connected to exchanges it was connected to. I've tried everything I could google or youtube to recover my wallet..nothing has worked. PLEASE HELP
I use chrome browser I uninstalled then installed metamask. it asked if i wanted a new wallet I declined and elected to put in my 12 word seed phrase (skipping a space between words)it told me seed phrase was invalid so i tried without skipping a space then put in a new password and checked the "agree to terms box. However, the blue Import button didn't light up. I tried this several times with no success. In desperation I have created another Metamask wallet on Chrome to see if I could recover my old wallet. This didn't help and now i feel as though I mat have made matters worse? I contacted via email Metamask support but have not heard back. Could anyone give me some advice please and thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest to contact Metamask support directly, don't remove or uninstall anything any change may diminish the posiblity of recovery. To check balances you can use myethereumwallet or mycrypto app with the seed phrase.

Comment: Thank you Ismael for your comment and help.